# PHPWORD Footer Text alignment issue

Tags: php, phpword

I am using phpword to generate a word file. I am having a problem with the footer. In the footer, I have page numbers and a text Confidential Document. The page numbers have to be aligned left and the Confidential Document has to be aligned right. I tried the below script but both text and page numbers are aligned to left only.

```
$phpword_object = new PHPWord();
$section = $phpword_object->createSection();

$footer = $section->createFooter();
$footer->addPreserveText('Page {PAGE} of {NUMPAGES}.',     
array(
    'align' => 'end',
    'positioning' => 'absolute'
));

$text = 'Confidential Document';

$footer->addPreserveText( $text,
    array(
        'align' => 'start',
        'positioning' => 'absolute'
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd do this with a simple right-aligned tab. It's far easier to understand, both in code form and also once you have the docx file open in Word in front of you.

So, assuming you have an A4 page with 2.5cm margin on either side, that gives you a 16cm wide area, so put the tab @ 16cm, something like this (this code works - I just tried it):

```
$phpWord->addParagraphStyle('footer_paragraph', array('tabs' => array(new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Tab('right', \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::cmToTwip(16)))));

$footer = $section->addFooter();

$footer->addPreserveText('Page {PAGE} of {SECTIONPAGES}' . "\u{0009}Confidential Document", 'your_own_font_style', 'footer_paragraph');
```

Comment: I made an assumption that you wanted both pieces of text to be on the same line - is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this **PHPWord Footer Text** alignment issue, you can use the table with row and cells to display the text and page number in single line with left-right alignment.
To display text on left align and page number on right align, I have applied this solution and it works for me.

```
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$footer = $section->addFooter();
$table = $section->addTable();
$table->addRow();

$cell = $table->addCell(4500);
$textrun = $cell->addTextRun();
$textrun->addText('left text', array('size' => 11), array('align'=>'left'));
$table->addCell(4500)->addPreserveText('{PAGE}', array('size' => 11), array('align'=>'right'));
```